# Экспорт объектов в Excel C# через буфер обмена

Tags: c#, .net, excel

Нужно скопировать содержимое List через буфер обмена в таблицу Excel. Пройдёт ли преобразование List в Datatable с последующей вставкой в таблицу? Или есть другие способы? Желательно с примером.

Comment: Скорее всего в силу того что данные в excel представлены в виде таблицы в трёх своеобразных обёртках, перенести подобным образом данные из буфера обмена проблематично. Однако перенос данных из одной таблицы excel в другую каким-то образом всё же осуществляется через буфер. Думаю с такими вопросами надо обращатсья напрямую в саппорт microsoft, но боюсь они не ответят )

Comment: Другие способы - создание нового excel файла с помощью NPOI или EPPlus и запись данных в него

Comment: Если ответ вас не устроил или не подходит - задавайте дополнительные вопросы

Answer (score 1):

Я написал такой кусочек кода:

```
var data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
foreach (var f in data.GetFormats())
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Скопировал несколько ячеек в Excel в буфер обмена и запустил. Для Excel 2010 вывод получился такой:

> ```
> EnhancedMetafile
> System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile
> MetaFilePict
> Bitmap
> System.Drawing.Bitmap
> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource
> Biff12
> Biff8
> Biff5
> SymbolicLink
> DataInterchangeFormat
> XML Spreadsheet
> HTML Format
> Text
> UnicodeText
> System.String
> CSV
> Rich Text Format
> Embed Source
> Object Descriptor
> Link Source
> Link Source Descriptor
> Link
> Format129
> ```

Т.е. из Excel данные можно вставить в одном из этих форматов, соответственно можно предположить, что и вставка в Excel может быть выполнена в одном из этих форматов. Проще всего сделать это в `CSV`, просто отделите свои элементы символом `;` если их нужно разместить горизонтально или символом перевода строки, если вертикально.
Например:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 10, 15, 23, 17, -8, 999, 4, 0 };
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue, string.Join("\n", list));
```

Если после выполнения этого кусочка кода выполнить вставку в Excel, то вставится столбец чисел.

Обратите внимание, при использовании формата `CSV` и строковых данных, если строка содержит символ `;`, то ее нужно обернуть в кавычки `"..."`, если при этом в строке также содержатся символы кавычек, то их нужно будет продублировать: `"...""...""..."`